# Inserting a node into the n-th position in a LinkedList for Hackerrank Java

Tags: java, linked-list

I am working on the Hackerrank question of [inserting a node into the n-th position in a LinkedList](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/insert-a-node-at-a-specific-position-in-a-linked-list).

Attached is my proposed solution:

I am basically traversing the LL until my `currentPos` is the same as the `position` variable, and then linking the previous node's next as the node we want to insert, set the node we want to insert's next as the current node.

```
Node InsertNth(Node head, int data, int position) {
    Node myNode = new Node();
    myNode.data = data;

    if(head == null) {
        myNode.next = null;
        return myNode;
    }

    int currentPos = 0;

    Node myHead = head;

    Node trackedNode = new Node();

    // 2 -> null
    // head -> null

    // 1 -> 2 -> null
    // head head.next null
    if(position == 0) {
        myNode.next = head;
        return myNode;
    }

    while(currentPos - 1 < position && myHead.next != null) {
        // Keeps track of previous node
        trackedNode = myHead;

        // Next node
        myHead = myHead.next;
        currentPos++;
    }

    if(currentPos == position) {

        trackedNode.next = myNode;
        myNode.next = myHead;
        return head;
    }

    return head;
}
```

For some reason, my code never executes beyond the first test case:

[image]

I've been racking my brain to try to solve this but I have no clue why.

Comment: `if(head == null) {` means that the subsequent `head.data = data;` will throw a NPE too.

Comment: @AndyTurner fixed by initializing a new Node and setting the data prior to the if-statement.

Comment: would you mind editing your question to show that? Your current code will throw an NPE.

Comment: How does `myNode` get inserted into the list?